# Pre-Populated Date in Text Field

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I am trying to pre-populate a text box with today's date, but for some reason, it keeps showing today's date as 5/30/13, which is a month behind.  This code should just be pulling the local time so why is it a month behind?  Here is my code, can someone please tell me why the current date is off...Please help, :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
function my_curr_date() {      
var currentDate = new Date()
  var day = currentDate.getDate();
  var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
var my_date = month+"-"+day+"-"+year;
document.getElementById("dateField").value=my_date;

}
function orderReady(orderTime){
dateToday.setDate(dateToday.getDate()+orderTime);
var ready=dateToday.getMonth()+"/"
+dateToday.getDate()+"/"+dateToday.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("duedateField").value=due_date;
}
/*]]>*/
```

```
<body onload='return my_curr_date();'>
```

---

```
<p>Today's Date<br />
<input type='text' name='dateField' id='dateField' value='' /><br />
Pick-up Date<br />
<input type='text' name='duedateField' id='duedateField' value='' /></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Date.getMonth:

> The value returned by getMonth is an integer between 0 and 11. 0
>   corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth).

Comment: Better to reference [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.4).

Answer (score 0):

HTML Element:

```
<p>Today's Date<br />
<input id="date" type="text" name="curDate" size="50" /><br />
Pick-up Date<br />
<input type='text' name='duedateField' id='duedateField' value='' /></p>
```

Use this javascript:

```
var month = Date.getMonth();
var date = Date.getDate();
var year = Date.getYear();
var deliverymonth;
var deliverydate;
var deliveryyear;    


var message = month + "/" + date + "/" + year;
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML=message;
if(month == 11 && date >= 29){
    deliveryyear = year + 1;
    deliverymonth = 1;
    deleverydate = date - 28;
}else{


     switch(month)
    {
        case 0,2,4,6,7,9,11:
             if(date >= 29){
                 deliverymonth = month + 1;
                 deliverydate = date - 28;
             }else{
                 deliverydate = date + 3;
             }
             break;
         case 3,5,8,10:
             if(date >= 28){
                 deliverymonth = month + 1;
                 deliverydate = date - 27;
             }else{
                 deliverydate = date + 3;
             }
             break;
          case 1:
             if(date >= 26){
                 deliverymonth = month + 1;
                 deliverydate = date - 25;
             }else{
                 deliverydate = date + 3;
             }
             break;
          default:
             break;
          }
var deliverymessage = deliverymonth + "/" + deliverydate + "/" + deliveryyear;
document.getElementById('duedateField').innerHTML=deliverymessage;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses...
I am still running into issues where no the field is not populating at all.  I am including the total script below for you to see.  I am so confused as to why this isn't working.  

Again, your help has been and is much appreciated.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

var month = Date.getMonth();
var date = Date.getDate();
var year = Date.getYear();
var message = month + "/" + date + "/" + year;
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML=message;

function loadDate(){
 var today=dateToday.getMonth() + "/"
 +dateToday.getDate()+"/"+dateToday.getFullYear();
 document.forms[0].curDate.value=today;
}
function orderReady(orderTime){
 dateToday.setDate(dateToday.getDate()+orderTime);
 var ready=dateToday.getMonth()+"/"
 +dateToday.getDate()+"/"+dateToday.getFullYear();
 document.forms[0].puDate.value=ready;
}
/*]]>*/
</script>

Comment: Ok, so I got the date to prepopulate correctly, but now the picker won't work.  Basically, I have to pre-populate the 1st text box with the current date, then populate the 2nd text box with the date + 1-3 days based on the radio box chosen.  I have updated my code with the full Javascript code so you can see what it is I'm doing.

Comment: see my edit for added content